# How to play a specifc audio file from Android in build rintone list?

Tags: android, ringtone

I need to know is it possible to play a particular audio file from android in-built ringtone files. For example assume Tone_23 is in android ringtone list, now i need to play this particular tone, when i click a button. I searched in Google i got a guidance how to call/show RingtonePicker Activity (The entire Ringtone list will be displayed). If this possible means, kindly share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some thing like this :

```
/**
 * Play ring tone.
 *
 * @param ringToneTitle the ring tone title
 */
void playRingTone(String ringToneTitle) {
    RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(
            getApplicationContext());
    ringtoneManager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

    int length = ringtoneManager.getCursor().getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Ringtone mRingtone = ringtoneManager.getRingtone(i);
        if (mRingtone != null) {
            Log.d("ringtoneTitle ", mRingtone.getTitle(getApplicationContext()));
            if(ringToneTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(mRingtone
                        .getTitle(getApplicationContext())) {
                mRingtone.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Added : Also have a look at this class [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

`RingtoneManager provides access to ringtones, notification, and other types of sounds. It manages querying the different media providers and combines the results into a single cursor. It also provides a Ringtone for each ringtone. We generically call these sounds ringtones, however the TYPE_RINGTONE refers to the type of sounds that are suitable for the phone ringer.`

Comment: i get the total number of ringtone list, now i need to print the ringtone names whaterver present in the list. how can i do this.

Comment: Please check, I have updated the answer with this statement
`Log.d("ringtoneTitle ", mRingtone.getTitle(getApplicationContext()));`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works good,now i need to play one of the audio file in the list, so i use the uri content://media/internal/audio/media/162 but it throw exception and the file won't play. Why it will happens

Comment: @Aerrow Which exception it throws? Can you please provide the full stack trace?

Comment: I used below code to play the audio file MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
       "content://media/internal/audio/media/186");
     mediaPlayer.reset();
     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
     mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
     mediaPlayer.start();                                                  and i will get the following error,  09-26 16:21:03.320: W/System.err(10425): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/internal/audio/media/186: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: You cannot directly access a ringtone file using `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "content://media/internal/audio/media/186");` because the file are internally managed by system using ContentProvider like a MediaProvider in this case.

Comment: Basically `"content://media/internal/audio/media/186"` is a content uri not a path to a particular file. Check this for reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Comment: Your solution would be to use `public void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)` method of MediaPlayer class and this will resolve your issue. 
ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only play the ringtone that is set in the system automatically with for example:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();
```

If you would always want to play a specific tone/file you would have to add it to your assets and play it from there.

Comment: @SunniSonic: your mean, i can only play the device default ringtone only. am i right?

Comment: if you refer to the default ringtone as to the one the user set then you are right. you are able to play those. For example if you have set "hit me baby one more time" :D as your ringtone you are able to start that one but not the other ones. any other one you would have to have as an asset. especially because all phone makers dont all have the same ringtones. that way your app would only work on certain devices.