# How to use Android studio Ringtonemanager.TYPE_RINGTONE

Tags: android, alarm

I need to sound an alarm ringtone after a layout popup with a stop button...
I had use if else, 
if (usenotification), I'm able to make a ringtone sounds

but in else (), it doesn't work..

This is my code:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    Uri uriRingtone;
    Ringtone ringTone;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

        uriRingtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmSound == null) {
            ringTone = RingtoneManager
                .getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uriRingtone);
        }

       uriRingtone = alarmSound;
    }
}
```

*the if part works... only else doesnt... // another part of java

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1337;

    Uri uriRingtone;
    Ringtone ringTone;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctxt);
        boolean useNotification = prefs.getBoolean("use_notification", true);
        if (useNotification) {
            NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) ctxt
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat, "It's Lunch time!", System.currentTimeMillis());
            PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, new Intent(ctxt, AlarmActivity.class), 0);

            note.setLatestEventInfo(ctxt, "Lunch!", i);
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            if(alarmSound == null){
                alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

            }
            note.sound = alarmSound;
            note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);

        } else {

            Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AlarmActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctxt.startActivity(i);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `if/else` example that you've tried also in the code above?

Comment: Nope it's in OnAlarmReceiver.. refer to my edit.. any help is appreciated..

Comment: I managed to make the if (usenotification) works...
but i need the else to sound a  ringtone when AlarmActivity intent is called out. @summea

Comment: In my app, users are able to check 'Use notification' (in android) or uncheck. If unchecked, when the alarm ring, it will open my new intent (AlarmActivity), however there is no ringtone..

Comment: Basically when the 'Use notification' is unchecked (else), when the set alarm rings, it will jump into (AlarmActivity with a stop button). But there is no ringtone sounded.. @summea

Comment: Would something like [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12588864/1167750) work for now?

Comment: I don't require media player, I need to play it as default ringtone.. I need to use ringtonemanager.TYPE_RINGTONE @summea

Comment: Is the intent supposed to be notifcation? Where can I add this to my code? I think we are getting close @summea :)

Comment: Hmm, have you tried adding `ringTone.play()` near the end of the `onCreate()` function in your `AlarmActivity` class?

Comment: Hey! It works @Summea now I've to make the sound stop when I press stop button/home/back

Comment: @summea You've been a great help! thank you! :) do you have any idea how to stop on OnPause and OnDestroy? Ive to make it stop ringing when the user click back or home..

Comment: At this point, I think it'd be a good idea for you to post an "update" to your original question above... by updating the code that you have at this point, and adding the additional question about `onPause()` and `onDestroy()`. This can help others and myself to hopefully find a way to help!